# How can i get errors out of Apollo client in a React front end using GQL

Tags: reactjs, error-handling, apollo, apollo-client, gql

I have a react app that uses Apollo/GQL, thru redux sagas which call the GQL queries/mutations

im instantiating the apolloClient using:

```
import ApolloClient from "apollo-client";

//.....

const apolloClient = new ApolloClient({
    link: httpLink,
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
    queryDeduplication: false,
    });
```

i need to

1. get access to the error array in apollo
2. have some operation run so i can use the error, for now lets jsut say i need to print the error to the console.

The docs are kind of lacking (even apollo docs mention many inquiries about how to do this and their need to add info)

most of their walk thrus show queries being called from the component, not thru a redux store and the async/saga complication as well.

how do i access the error array from apollo and how do i callback on it and run an operation with the error (Hooks, etc, however)?

i need to be able to do this client-side

Comment: I believe the official docs here would be useful for you perhaps regarding using onError from Apollo Link: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/link/apollo-link-error/

Answer (score 1):

```
const errorControl =  onError(({ networkError, graphQLErrors }) => {
  if (graphQLErrors) {
    graphQLErrors.map(({ message, locations, path }) => {
      toast.error("There was an error accessing the database, please try again later");
    });
  }
  if (networkError) {
    toast.error("There was a network error, please try again later");
  }
});
```

from an uncredited stack overflow post.

then concat ur link in the instantiation of he new ApolloClient

```
link: errorControl.concat(httpLink)
```